# setting up numpy/scipy in idle

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-idle

I would like to use numpy in a python program I am creating, but I can not figure out how to use it inside of IDLE. The download page for numpy redirects to the one for Scipy, which is fine, infact I would like to download the rest of Scipy as well (especially matPlotLib), but it isn't as important to me as numpy, but the scipy download page tells you to get it from even larger packages, none of which I can figure out how to use in IDLE. Note that I use the python 2.x series, and I also use other installed packages in the same program such as pygame, and wxpython. Thank you so much.

Comment: To use numpy in IDLE, there is absolutely nothing extra you have to do. Install it the same way you'd install it without IDLE, and it works in IDLE.

Comment: Beyond that, nobody can possibly give you any further help without (a) knowing which platform you're on, and (b) knowing where in the instructions you've gotten stuck.

Comment: I use Windows 8 and, python version 2.7.3 I got to this download page http://www.scipy.org/install.html and tried nearly all of them, and they would set up their own environment to use, but I want it in IDLE. Sorry for not explaining that part earlier.

Comment: I think my problem is not knowing how to install Numpy

Comment: If you scroll down that page: "Christoph Gohlke provides [pre-built Windows installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for many Python packages, including all of the core Scipy stack." Just look at the specification to see the list of packages you need, then download and install them.

Comment: Thank you you are right. I did not see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation you linked](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) says:

> You can assemble the Scipy stack from individual packages. For details of what you need, see [the specification](http://www.scipy.org/stackspec.html#stackspec).
>
> ...
>
> Christoph Gohlke provides [pre-built Windows installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) for many Python packages, including all of the core Scipy stack.

So, make a list of the main packages you want, check the specification to see the other dependencies you'll need to install to use those packages, go to the pre-built installer page, download them, and run the installers.

Obviously you need to download the installers corresponding to your Python. You didn't say whether you're using 64-bit or 32-bit Python, and you need to know that. The only other thing you need to know is which Python version you're using, and you already said that was 2.7.

Comment: But how do you import it into IDLE?

Comment: @Imray: The same way you import it into the command-line interactive interpreter, or a script: `import numpy as np`, etc.